# Get element contents of an html file using a php file without using post method of Form element

Tags: php, html

i've got an html file with some elements and their contents (that can change).
In this html file, in the script section, i use jquery to load a php file when a button is pressed but i also would like that when file php is loaded, the php file could get some (modified) elements of the file html that loaded it.

Example

```
    $("#mybutton").click(function()
        {


            $("#loadingzone").load("file.php",
                    function(resp,stat,xhr)
                    {
                        if (stat=="error") alert("Error "+xhr.status+" : "+xhr.statusText);
                    });

<script>
```

...

```
   <div id="div1">this is a dynamic content that can change</div>

   <button id="mybutton">Button to load call the php file</button>

   <div id="loadingzone"></div>
```

...

I would like my php file could get content of that div ( i mean that with id="div1") when the php file is loaded thought the jquery script.

I can't put the elements in a form and so, i can't use the $post in my php file.
How can i do it?

Comment: Thank u! And then, how to get it from the php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it via your AJAX request. It must not be the *POST* method. To make it *GET* method just append as parameter to the URL. Because it is passed directly in the URL it has to be encoded.

```
$("#loadingzone").load(
    "file.php?text=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("div1").innerText),
    (esp, stat, xhr) => { ... }
);
```

Now, in *file.php* script you can access the *GET* parameter

```
$textFromAjaxRequest = $_GET['text'];
```